# phpmyadmin mysql double underscore, issue in xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I have overcome a recent issue, however the rectification of which has left me somewhat confused. I have been running an XAMPP server on OSX, and have been happily coding in php and css...No problems. I came onto a tutorial for using mysql (I am learning) and decided to give it go. I managed to get onto phpmyadmin, however was faced with the persistent 1932 error: phpmyadmin__tracking.pma cannot be found etc.. I was curious as to the double underscore - and delved into the config.inc.php file and deciding to change all the double underscores (in all documents) to single underscore. And BINGO. Problem solved. I am just wondering:

1) Have I undermined the integrity of my server, and therefore my future learning (developing on compromised setup)

2) have I been lucky and stumbled upon a solution (which does not appear to be well documented on the internet) and;

3) I could not find this information anyway, therefore hopefully me posting this on stack overflow will help others searching for the same issue...which to be seems to be the purpose of this site. Hope I have helped someone, I would really appreciate a response from someone who can advise as to my issue.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

At some point we changed single underscore to double underscore in these table names, see https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/3a5843a7cd49001ef4f5735a02057290f13024b7  so the "official" way is now using double underscore. What you did is fine, but it reflects the fact that the table names you have in your pmadb did not match what was configured.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use certain phpMyAdmin (pma) features you have to import the script /examples/create_tables.sql from your pma file folder. This will create a database named phpmyadmin and all of those tables which were formerly missing.

I really do not understand why your "solution" worked.

Comment: To clarify, no files were missing - I was simply met with a pop-up mysql error which said this #1932 table 'phpmyadmin.pma_tracking' doesn't exist in engine.  I then navigated to the config file, where I saw about 15 files, named X__Y.php - with TWO underscores. I deleted one underscore, and the issue was solved. I am wondering how these appeared in the first place as I have not messed around with the file. Also, have a created a temporary fix which will screw things up further down the line? Thanks Max

Comment: Those lines you changed in config file just activate certain pma features. Those features require a set of tables to exist. The standard table names are thos x__y names you changed. Those tables would have been created by the sql script I mentioned in my solution. Actually those tables may be named like you want it. Its just important that those names in config file and the actual tables names match. So you did not screw anything up, you just created a "custom" setup. I dont know why those table names with just one underscore did exist but in the end it does bnot matter. Everything fine ;-)